# Ruby on Rails get unique country from Query results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following were my query to get list of products:

```
@listed_products = @products.where(:step => 5, :status => 1)
                            .includes(:product_attachments)
                            .includes(:product_reviews)
                            .order("created_at desc")
```

The result return products which also consist many similar `country` eg:

```
name:prod1
city:city1
country:A

name:prod2
city:city3
country:A

name:prod3
city:city5
country:B
```

How can I filter out just unique country `A,B` from the result query? I just need country list to build a drop down list for user to sort product based on country. Thanks!!

Comment: Given the resultset above, what `prod` should be returned for `country:A`: `prod1`, `prod2` or random? Whether you need the country list, why on the Earth you want to get it from `products` query?

Comment: @mudasobwa can `@listed_products` be extended just to list out name of unique country? eg `@listed_products_country` for list country name.

Comment: Hey for uniq countries you just use `@products.where(:step => 5, :status => 1).pluck(:country).uniq` instead of using this additional includes beacuse as per your query it will have no meaning after uniq contries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this -

```
@listed_products = @products.where(:step => 5, :status => 1)
                        .includes(:product_attachments)
                        .includes(:product_reviews)
                        .order("products.created_at desc")

result = @listed_products.pluck(:country).uniq
```

Comment: I need separate query, `@listed_products` is just to list down all the lists.

Comment: `@listed_products.pluck(:country).uniq` - this should do the work if you have all the records in `@listed_products` already.

Comment: @d3bug3r which error you are getting ? can you try this in your console and show the result.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "created_at" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ...step" = $2 AND "products"."status" = $3  ORDER BY created_at...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "products"."country" FROM "products" LEFT OUTER JOIN "product_attachments" ON "product_attachments"."product_id" = "products"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "product_reviews" ON "product_reviews"."product_id" = "products"."id" WHERE "products"."user_id" = $1 AND "products"."step" = $2 AND "products"."status" = $3  ORDER BY created_at desc):`

Comment: @d3bug3r I have edited the answer. please give it a try. I have changed `order("created_at desc")` to `order("products.created_at desc")` . There is an `AmbiguousColumn: ERROR` . So you may need to specify `created_at` belongs to which table. I have assumed your table name is `products` here.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
   @listed_products = @products.where(:step => 5, :status => 1)
                            .includes(:product_attachments)
                            .includes(:product_reviews)
                            .order("created_at desc").uniq.pluck(:country)
```